# Salesforce: Outbound Change and API Names

Tags: salesforce, custom-fields

(Given that the field already exists in production) If I update a custom field's API name in sandbox and add it to an outbound change, will it updated the API name in production or will it create a new field?

Answer (score 0):

It will create new field. Metadata API tracks field, objects etc by developer name, not by Id. For example lets say you made the change via Eclipse so you're saving new version of object definition.

1. Salesforce will notice you're not sending `Old_name__c` anymore but there's `New_name__c`.
2. will happily merge what you're sending with server data
3. Will send you back new definition of object that contains `Old_Name__c` and `New_name__c`

Yes, this is bit painful. You can delete the old field with so-called destructive changes deployment (can't be done with changesets) but then there are all these little places where you should add the new field back: page layouts, profiles, listviews, report types, reports...

It's almost always not worth the hassle and I end up doing renames manually before main deployment (and again - this can be a "fun" ride if the field is used in apex, has to be commented out first).